# apply negative value with variable using .css with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, margin, negative-number

I have a syntax issue as I want to do something quite simple. Apply a negative value to a variable using `.css`.

Here yo have the code:

```
var figureImage = $('.js-image-centering');
var figureImageHeight = figureImage.height();
var figureImageWidth = figureImage.width();
var figureImageMarginLeft = (0-(figureImageWidth/2));
var figureImageMarginTop = (0-(figureImageHeight/2));

figureImage.css('margin-left', figureImageMarginLeft);
figureImage.css('margin-top', figureImageMarginTop);
```

I would like to forget about `figureImageMarginLeft` and `figureImageMarginTop`. So, its it possible to something like this?

```
figureImage.css('margin-left', -figureImageMarginLeft);
```

How do you write it correctly?

Comment: you dont need to do `(0-(figureImageWidth/2))`, doing `-figureImageWidth/2` is fine.

Comment: If you dont know that `figureImageMarginLeft` is **-ve** or **+ve**, then you can do, `-Math.abs(figureImageMarginLeft)` to get negative number always.

Comment: @AshishKumar This worked perfectly, but I would like to know for a future how to apply this negative value on the .css field if I need it.

Comment: @AshishKumar Steve Robinson answer was the correct one, but I would like to know what method would be better for speed quality or best practices

Comment: ok, so Steve's answer looks great. But I prefer to pass javascript object in `.css()`, as this allows you to set multiple CSS properties at once. like: `$("div").css({marginLeft : -margin});`. So this way you can also do something like `$("div").css({marginLeft : -margin, color: '#F00', padding: 10});`

Comment: In jQuery you dont need to specify `px` as unit for `.css()` or `.animate()` or `.height()` etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes Absolutely. If you do,

```
var a = 100;
$(".stuff").css("margin-left",-a)
```

the element would get the rule: `margin-left: -100px`

Answer (score 0):

What about `figureImage.css('margin-left', "-" + figureImageMarginLeft + 'px');`?

Comment: If I do so, the value is not displayed at all. So this code is not making it work at all. Do you have any other input?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```
var mL = -30;
$("div").css("marginLeft", mL + "px");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/6GNVQ/)

Answer (score 0):

That will do the trick (will make positive values negative and negatives positiv):

```
figureImage.css('margin-left', -figureImageMarginLeft+"px");
```

or, if you want it to be always negative:

```
figureImage.css('margin-left', -Math.abs(figureImageMarginLeft)+"px");
```

always positiv:

```
figureImage.css('margin-left', Math.abs(figureImageMarginLeft)+"px");
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/rN3cw/